# Bootstrap Sticky navbar is causing vertical scrolling in collapsed mode

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a `navbar` that is supposed to stick to the top of the page. I used `.navbar-fixed-top` class to accomplish that and gave the body element, a padding of `70px`. Now in the collapsed mode (mobile resolution), when toggled, it gives a vertical navigation.

Not sure where this scrolling is coming from.

**Here's the code:**

```html
<header class=" container-fluid navbar-fixed-top">

  <!-- header navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="market.html"><img src="images/logo-inner.jpg" / alt="B-Hive: Expand your business"></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

        <!-- Form search start -->
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" class="top-search-padding">
          <div class="form-group">

            <div class="search-div ui-widget">
              <input id="tags" type="text" class="txt-search" placeholder="Search people, products and services">

              <button type="submit" class="btn-search"><img src="images/search-icon.png" /></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <!-- Form search end -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="top-menu-links-active"><a href="#">MARKET</a></li>
          <li><a class="top-menu-links" href="#">EXHIBITIONS</a></li>
          <li><a class="top-menu-links" href="#">MESSAGES</a></li>
          <li><a class="top-menu-links" href="#">DASHBOARD</a></li>
          <li><a class="top-menu-links" href="#">CART</a></li>
          <li class="profile-pic-padding"></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle custom-dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img class="" src="images/profile-pic.fw.png" /> <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>

              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Switch Accounts</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>

              <li><a href="#">Language <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">EN</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">ع</a></li>

                </ul>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </li>



        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <!-- /header navbar -->

</header>
```

Comment: have you bootstrap's css and js files..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap's `.navbar-collapse` has a default `max-height: 340px;` which causes scrollbars to appear when the links inside the navigation exceed this height.

You can simply remove this property to avoid the scrollbars from appearing in mobile view.

Comment: Thanks so much! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use header on the top ,Just start from the nav

```
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
           <div class="container-fluid">
           <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-     
          toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"   
         aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"    
     role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span  
      class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"   
     role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span 
       class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
           </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
          </nav>
```

Comment: Doesn't make any difference. Because then I will have to use the .navbar-fixed-top to the navbar itself.

Comment: how can you use navbar in header section ,use it in the body

Comment: Sir, this is the <header> tag written in the <body> section.

Comment: Replace your code with mine ,and then you will find the difference

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="Sr-only"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="market.html"><img src="images/logo-inner.jpg" /> alt="B-Hive: Expand your business"></a>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <div id="mainuldiv" class="navbar navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav mynavbar" style="float:right;">
                    <li class="top-menu-links-active"><a href="#">MARKET</a></li>
                    <li><a class="top-menu-links" href="#">EXHIBITIONS</a></li>
                    <li><a class="top-menu-links" href="#">MESSAGES</a></li>
                    <li><a class="top-menu-links" href="#">DASHBOARD</a></li>
                    <li><a class="top-menu-links" href="#">CART</a></li>
                    <li class="profile-pic-padding"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle custom-dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img class="" src="images/profile-pic.fw.png" /> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>

                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Switch Accounts</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Language <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">EN</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">ع</a></li>

                                </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And also mention this files:
Bootstrap.min.css,bootstrap.min.js & jquery.min.js